# Beamer metropolis theme issue

Tags: beamer, xetex, luatex, themes, beamer-metropolis

So I am trying to get metropolis beamer theme work. 
For some reason, it worked on my El Capitain mac with no problem using LuaLaTeX.

But the exact same file does not work on my Yosemite mac.

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}           
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code compiles with latex and xelatex without using the theme default font Fira. 
When I run it with LuaLaTeX on my Yosemite mac, here is the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\checkfont #1^^@-\suppressfontnotfounderror 
                                          =1\font \x = "#1" at 10pt \selectf...
```

I installed the theme the same way I installed on the El Capitain mac, and I cannot seem to figure out why it does not compile with the Fira font for metropolis.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No problem here.  Is your MacTeX up-to-date?

Comment: yes, both machines have the same MacTex. I installed the Fira fonts to my mac as well. But LuaLaTeX does not work.

Comment: Could you upload the log to a PasteBin service, such as [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [Hastebin](http://hastebin.com/)?  As such, the error message you posted doesn't really reveal *which* control sequence was undefined.

Comment: Of course, here it is http://hastebin.com/kagewalavu.vhdl   Thank you.

Comment: You definitely have an outdated version.  `\suppressfontnotfounderror` is the undefined control sequence which is a primitive in recent versions of LuaTeX, thus it can't be undefined (unless you undefined it).

Comment: Also your log says `texlive/2013`.  I guess it's time for an update anyway.

Comment: so I installed the fita font to my mac - like a regular font and then it worked: only with xelatex not with lualatex :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by updating the TeX system installed.